# Excel - remove duplicate rows from a list

Tags: excel-2007

I have not got much experience in Excel.Any help appreciated.
I have 10-11 csv files , that can be opened in excel. I have duplicate records in all the files.I need to count the unique records in all the files that matches column3(for e.g).

cheers

Comment: are all the files the same format i.e. same columns and same datatypes in each column?

Answer (score 0):

You could link the CSV files from an Access database, then UNION all the tables, that would get rid of any duplicate rows, then a simple query on the UNION would allow you to count rows with specific criteria.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

try using this formula to identify duplicate and non-duplicate records.  Here I'm assuming that all of your data is on one sheet, and the unique value to check for duplicate-iness is col3.  Also, Im checking all the way down to row 2000.  If you have more rows, change the range in the formula.

```
=IF(MAX(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$2000,$C$2:$C$2000))>1,"Duplicates","No Duplicates")
```

No all you gotta do is count how many Duplicates and how many No Duplicates you have.